# Define a dictionary externally for a python program

Tags: python, dictionary

My python program reads a pre-defined dictionary to get certain values for processing. I need to be able to change the values of the dictionary. But, as program will be converted to executable file, it should not be defined inside the program.

I was thinking like defining it in a text file. I don't want to write extra code to parse and populate dictionary. I need to know if there is any way to define a dict in a text file and assigning its content directly to python dict.

Like this:

**In the text file:**

`{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}`

NB: The actual one is bit more enrich with values. This is just an example.

**In the program:**
`dict_variable = f.read()`

So if you print the variable it will be a dictionary object:

`{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}`

and can be accessed like `dict_variable['a']`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Looks like serialization, look at pickle.

Comment: JSON would be a better fit, as it is readable/modifiable by humans. Note though that the example is invalid syntax; it uses list notation but contains keys/values.

Comment: Should I make this complicated. I just want the user to be able to update values as he will not be familiar with python code and I will be giving an executable which cannot be updated.:( I have corrected syntax:)

Comment: I would use JSON in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use eval() :

> s = f.read()
>
> d = eval(s)

From [Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/converting-a-string-to-dictionary)

Comment: That's a security issue, people can put any code they want in the file (as long as it's an expression, but that's easy) and have it executed.

Comment: file contents: `import os; os.system('rm -rf /')`

Comment: Absolutly. But it's not always a concern (ie : the input file may be mastered) and the link I gave points another, safer, solution, if needed.